# jquery animation not smooth

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, smoothing

i'n kinda new to JS and JQuery.
i'm trying to create a type of GuitarHero game in JQuery but the notes aren't falling smoothly 
what i'm doing is basically calling `setTimeout()` in a loop - each one with a different timeout (given in an array - the "song scipt" if you will).
the code looks like this:

```
while(counter < curSong.numNotes){
                // set the parameters sent to runCreateNote
        runCreateNote(counter, margin, entity, interval, name);
        counter++;
}
```

when `runCreateNote` calls `setTimeout()` (for scope purposes)

this is the animate code :

```
    noteBall.animate({
            top: (noteBall.parent().height() - noteBall.height()*2) + 'px'
        }, {
            duration: fallingtime,
            queue: false,
            easing: "linear",
            step: function() {
                checkStep(id);  
            },
            complete: function() {
                reachBottom(id);    
            }
    });

    function checkStep(id){

        var noteBall = $("#" + id);
        var name = id.substring(0,1);
        if (name == "R"){
            if (isInRange(noteBall)){
                isRedIn = true;
            } else {
                isRedIn = false;
            }
        }
        if (name == "B"){
            if (isInRange(noteBall)){
                isBlueIn = true;
            } else {
                isBlueIn = false;
            }
        }
        if (name == "G"){
            if (isInRange(noteBall)){
                isGreenIn = true;
            } else {
                isGreenIn = false;
            }
        }
        if (name = "O"){
            if (isInRange(noteBall)){
                isOrangeIn = true;
            } else {
                isOrangeIn = false;
            }
        }

}
```

i donnow if any of the code is relevant but i just wanted to show that the animation doesn't seen to be too heavy (i'd think it would run smoothly)

am i missing some key principle?

Answer (score 0):

Well, without seeing the rest of your code or a demo of the application, my guess would be that this is the line giving you problems:

```
top: (noteBall.parent().height() - noteBall.height()*2) + 'px'
```

If you could calculate those values ahead of time and cache them you'd probably be better off.

You also should consider taking all those if statements in checkStep and moving them into a switch statement (or at least if/else) -- assuming the cases are mutually exclusive.

Comment: i tried to calculate ahead and pass on as a var but still, no difference.
the problem was there nefore i ever put anything in checkStep so i don't think that's the problem.

if there's any other code anyone need - plz let me know and i'll post it... just didnt want to bother you with all of it